# Can a segfault be caused by another process?

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault

Suppose two separate applications A and B are running. Usually, a memory corruption in A will cause A to crash with segfault error leaving application B unaffected.

But can memory corruption in A (intentional or otherwise) cause segfault in B while A continues executing?

My OS is Linux.

Answer (score 1):

General answer:

In an OS without "memory protection" ...
*(which generally requires an "MMU", Memory Management Unit, [hardware functionality])*
... one application/subprocess/task may cause another task to fail or misbehave by
"stomping" on (changing) the code or data of the second task.

This should not be possible in an OS that HAS memory protection (e.g. Linux).
But may still happen in practice, due to "loopholes" or imperfections in the implementation of the protection.
*Or even be caused by broken hardware (RAM, ROM, MMU, CPU, IRQ, ...) - which may be VERY intermittent in nature, temperature dependent, or anything similar[1].*

[1] e.g. an IC that provides 'functions' to the OS, e.g. an IRQ source that is used for only a specific task may be broken - thus causing trouble only when that function is actually used.

Comment: To add to that, memory corruption can also appear on its own, i.e. due to bad memory or effects from environment.